# Python: Batch rename files in a directory using a predefined list, sorting by date created

Tags: python, excel, loops, sorting, pandas

I am downloading a number of PDF documents from an online repository, but they are not coming through with the proper naming conventions. The files align with a list of names that I have located in an Excel spreadsheet.

What I would like to do is import the Excel spreadsheet, assign the names to a variable, and then use os.rename() to rename the files I have downloaded as a batch in order to match my list.

When I download the .PDFs, each is given a random naming convention, rather than named by the URL. These are randomly generated each time the link is chosen. This is creating a problem because I cannot sort the documents in the proper order in order to name them in the proper order.

What I would like to do is sort the documents by "date created". By using sleep() I have the documents downloaded in the correct order, matching the instrument numbers, but I cannot figure out how to line them up properly to iterate through the names I would like to change.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
#Import packages
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import os

#Designate file locations / destinations
file = '/Users/username/Desktop/test.xlsx'
directory = '/Users/username/Downloads'

#Obtain instrument names
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1', parse_cols=[2], names=['instrument'])
names = df1.instrument
prefix = xyz

#Obtain file location
imported_files = os.listdir(directory)
imported_files.remove('.DS_Store')
df1['importedFiles'] = imported_files
print(df1)

       instrument     importedFiles
0      146169-1975   2461030_123.PDF
1      147235-1975  2461030_2027.PDF
2      148367-1975   2461030_348.PDF
3      149563-1975  2461030_5327.PDF
4      171413-1977   2461030_555.PDF
5      186305-1977  2461030_5969.PDF
6      186726-1977  2461030_7610.PDF
7      186727-1978  2461030_7878.PDF
8      187748-1978  2461030_8733.PDF

#Set working directory
os.chdir('/Users/username/Downloads')

#Set a loop to rename 
for x, y in zip(names, os.listdir('/Users/username/Downloads')):
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(y)
    new_names = ('{}_{}{}'.format(prefix, x, file_ext))
    print(new_names)
    os.rename(y, new_names)
    sleep(0.5)
```

When I print "new_names" the order of the names come out correctly in my console. However, when I take the next step to actually rename the files, the renaming doesn't work because of the randomly generated names coming from the imported files.

How can I make sure that the file names change in the same order that they are coming in? OR how can I change the order of the files so that when I name them, they match the instrument string's coming in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer to my own question! So in order to rename the files based on the instrument numbers I was pulling in from the Excel spreadsheet, I first had to reorganized the files I was downloading, which were generating the random numbers.

I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZP3y-gxyJg and used os.path.getatime on my directory to find the creation time, and then used a renaming loop to name them. This organized the files the way that I wanted, and I was able to rename them in the order I wanted. Here is the code I used:

```
iterfiles = iter(os.listdir('/Users/username/Desktop'))
next(iterfiles)

for file_time in iterfiles:
    time_stamp = os.path.getatime(file_time)
    local_time = time.ctime(time_stamp)
    ext = 'PDF'
    print(local_time)
    time_name = ('{}.{}'.format(local_time, ext))
    os.rename(file_time, time_name)
    sleep(0.5)

#--------RENAME FILES BASED ON NAME----------#
iterinstrument = iter(os.listdir('/Users/username/Desktop'))
next(iterinstrument)

for x, y in zip(instrument_numbers, iterinstrument):
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(y)
    number, year = x.split('-')
    number = number.zfill(7)
    new_names = ('{}-{}{}{}'.format(county, year, number, file_ext))
    print(new_names)
    os.rename(y, new_names)
    sleep(0.5)
```